# redirect urls from specific folder to external domains (with php?)

Tags: php, regex, redirect

The site i need this for is a wordpress site,

Basicly my /out/ folder is followed by an url of a partner. i want people that go to such a link to get forwarded to that url
I know there are plugins to do this manual,  but i will need thousands of urls, so i basicly want to do it with a wildcard somehow

Is this possible to do with php?

```
https://example.com/out/https://externaldomain.com
should go to https:// externaldomain.com
```

this part will change, but is always an url:

```
https://example.com/out/*  https:// externaldomain.com  *
```

So basicly "https:// example.com/out/" should vanish, leaving just the *  https:// externaldomain.com  * part

if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great

(i originally asked this question with the idea to do it with htaccess, but i believe this isn't possible to do like i want)

Comment: Do you use a routing system? Something like AltoRouter would help you achieve something like this.

Comment: currently not using anything (when i started i thought this would be a simple htaccess redirect)  (was mistaken on that :(  )  will need to look into this, have 0 experience with something like that :(

Comment: Just added an answer, I feel like that would be your best solution.

Comment: Something very simple such as `RewriteRule ^out/(.*) $1 [R=301,L]` should work, if you want to do it using .htaccess only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AltoRouter](https://altorouter.com/) is a routing class written in PHP (5.3+)

You can use it to your advantage here, it is really useful for creating views. This is without using `file.php?=%URL%`, but allows you to use `/out/https://example.com`.

**index.php**

```
<?php 

require("AltoRouter.php");

$router = new AltoRouter();

/* Routes */
/* $router->map(Method, Route , Target , Name) */

$router->map('GET|POST','/out/[*:url]', 'file.php', 'out');

/* Match route */
$match = $router->match();

/* Check if there is a match */
if($match) {
  header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  require $match['target'];
} else {
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  echo "Error 404";
}

?>
```

Then, you'll need another file, you can name this anything, just make sure that the name of the file matches the target in your router map.

**file.php**

```
<?php

/* Get the URL we need to redirect to */
$url = $match["params"]["url"];

/* Redirect to the URL */
header("location: $url");

/* Exit to prevent any further processing */
die();

?>
```

As far as I can tell, using just htaccess would not function properly. To use AltoRouter, you will need to add the following into your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

All of these files need to go into the root directory of your webserver. If you're not sure, it's typically inside of the public_html folder, but if you're unable to find it, contact your hosting provider.

Comment: i really did not expect such a detailed answer.  thanks a lot man!!
for the files, they go in my main directory not in the /out/  folder right?

Comment: @Phpnewb all of these files need to go into the main directory in order for it work, and no problem :)