# Rewriting URL with variable subdirectory not working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to be able to rewrite the following website structure so it applies to both the main domain, and then all subdirectories.

```
domain.ltd
|    | wp-content
|       | themes
|           | theme01
|               | core
|                   | web.php   # http://domain.ltd/wp-content/themes/theme01/core/web.php
|
|- subsite1
|   | wp-content/themes/theme02/core
|       | web.php               # http://domain.ltd/subsite1/wp-content/themes/theme02/core/web.php
|
|- subsite2
|   | wp-content/themes/theme03/core
|       | web.php               # http://domain.ltd/subsite2/wp-content/themes/theme03/core/web.php
```

I have the following `.htaccess` rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-])/ws/(.*) /wp-content/themes/$1/core/$2
```

But I cant figure out why it wont match. I have tried using the https://htaccess.madewithlove.be tester but couldn't find the correct pattern.

Essentially I would want the URLs to be:

```html
http://domain.ltd/ws/web.php
http://domain.ltd/subsite1/ws/web.php
http://domain.ltd/subsite2/ws/web.php
```

Comment: Using something like my solution here might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467883/redirect-urls-from-specific-folder-to-external-domains-with-php/57468117#57468117

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your question is missing some details, or there are mistakes, because it isn't fully explained how you want to redirect all variations of the URL.

If you want to redirect the "main domain" as you say, to `theme01` every time as a default, you will need a separate rule to match only that case when there is no "subdomain" in the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^/?ws/([\w\.-]+)$ /wp-content/themes/theme01/core/$1 [L]
```

This redirects `http://domain.ltd/ws/web.php` to `/wp-content/themes/theme01/core/web.php` and you are effectively treating `theme01` as the default theme.

You then need a second rule to redirect all variants containing a "subdomain" and use that as the theme name (which is what it seems like you want to do):

```
RewriteRule ^/?([\w-]+)/ws/([\w\.-]+)$ /wp-content/themes/$1/core/$2 [L]
```

This redirects `http://domain.ltd/subdomain2/ws/web.php` to `/wp-content/themes/subdomain2/core/web.php`.

Answer (score 1):

An simple solution if you don't mind, is simply create an ws folder and let all files inside it. Also, create an redirect rule in the root folder to your main website

```
domain.ltd/ws
|    | wp-content
|       | themes
|           | theme01
|               | core
|                   | web.php   # http://domain.ltd/wp-content/themes/theme01/core/web.php
|
|- subsite1
|   | wp-content/themes/theme02/core
|       | web.php               # http://domain.ltd/subsite1/wp-content/themes/theme02/core/web.php
|
|- subsite2
|   | wp-content/themes/theme03/core
|       | web.php               # http://domain.ltd/subsite2/wp-content/themes/theme03/core/web.php
```